# Deserializing a JSON Dictionary<int,CustomType> to List<CustomType>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to Deserialize a JSON Dictionary of type Dictionary to a List (List), I am using JSON.Net for this purpose. For sure its an amazing Library its just this that I am bit stuck !

I am subscribing to some API the Response is As you can see below:

```
    "team_details": {
                "0": {
                    "index": 1,
                    "team_id": "1..",
                    "team_name": "Research Team",
                    "team_url": "...",
                    "role": "Administrator"
                },
                "1": {
                    "index": 2,
                    "team_id": "2..",
                    "team_name": "WB Team",
                    "team_url": "...",
                    "role": "User"
                }
}
```

I need to use this to convert it to `List<Team>` where Teams:

```
Class Teams{

 public int Index{get;set;}

 public String TeamName{get;set;}

...
}
```

Comment: First, did you make sure your [JSON is valid](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: This JSON is valid, it's just a bit awkward that the list isn't stored as an array, but rather as key-value objects where the key is the index.

Comment: Yes it is Valid , and its internally lets say a JsON Dictionary.

Comment: It's valid only if you wrap braces around it. Make sure you have valid JSON before parsing.

Comment: I was counting that as a simple copy-paste typo.

Comment: I would deserialize to a `Dictionary<int,Team>` and then convert to a list by calling `teamdictionary.Values.ToList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, Team>` and then get the values into a list using `dictionary.Values.ToList()` when you need them.

However, if you would really rather have a `List<Team>` in your class definition, you can use a custom `JsonConverter` to do the conversion during deserialization.

```
public class TeamListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<Team>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        return token.Values().Select(v => v.ToObject<Team>()).ToList();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""team_details"": {
                ""0"": {
                    ""index"": 1,
                    ""team_id"": ""1.."",
                    ""team_name"": ""Research Team"",
                    ""team_url"": ""..."",
                    ""role"": ""Administrator""
                },
                ""1"": {
                    ""index"": 2,
                    ""team_id"": ""2.."",
                    ""team_name"": ""WB Team"",
                    ""team_url"": ""..."",
                    ""role"": ""User""
                }
            }
        }";

        RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        foreach (Team team in root.Teams)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(team.TeamName);
        }
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("team_details")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TeamListConverter))]
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    [JsonProperty("index")]
    public int Index { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("team_id")]
    public string TeamId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("team_name")]
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("team_url")]
    public string TeamUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Research Team
WB Team
```